# Adding default value to a dynamically added row

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not sure how to explain what I'm trying to do so here's the short version of my code:

```
var counter = 1;
    var currDate = new Date(),
    today = (currDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + currDate.getDate() + '/' + currDate.getFullYear();
    $("#btnAdd").click(function (event) {
        addRow = "<tr><td><input type='text' class='dateClass defaultDate' id='txtDate" + counter + "'/></td></tr>";
        event.preventDefault();
        counter++;
        $("#tblName").append(addRow);
        $("#txtDate" + counter).val(today);
        $(".dateClass").datepicker();
    });
```

The dynamically added row contains a textbox for the date which the user would select however, by default, the value of this would be the current date. Now, my problem is, everytime I click the add row button, the value of the previous textbox, would revert back to the default date even though I have already set a different date for it.

I know its because each of the added rows would have the class name defaultDate so I figured I'd have to use the id instead which would be txtDate + counter (i.e. txtDate2), however I'm not sure that's the right approach. So basically, how do I tell the button that when it adds a new row, it would only set the default date to the new row and should not change the previous row's current value?

Comment: You should have var counter = 1 outside the function otherwise the id of the <td> will always be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing things in a weird order

1. Use counter
2. Increment counter
3. Use counter again

The problem is that by 3. above it has been incrememnted. Just move this line:

```
counter++
```

to after this line:

```
$("#txtDate" + counter).val(today);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Nmk39/

Answer (score 1):

Try to put definition of counter

```
var counter = 1;
```

out of the all functions, otherwise it isn't a global variable and also, it resets in every button click to value 1 and all buttons have same id.

Then, the value needs to be assign by refering to the id:

```
$("#txtDate" + counter).val(today);
```

otherwise all input with the class are reset.

Comment: okay, so I gave it a quick try but it just created the new row with an empty textbox. I've updated my code to show how it currently looks like, including the value of the variable today.

Comment: counter++; should be in the end of the function then; because the counter variable is used twice in the function, but with different values

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
   var counter = 1;
        var currDate = new Date(),
        today = (currDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + currDate.getDate() + '/' + currDate.getFullYear();
        $("#btnAdd").click(function (event) {
            addRow = "<tr><td><input type='text' class='dateClass defaultDate' value='"+today+"'id='txtDate" + counter + "'/></td></tr>";
            event.preventDefault();
            counter++;
            $("body").append(addRow);
            $(".dateClass").datepicker();
        });
```